# Swift - UIAlertController post action

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a UIAlertController instance that pops to the user once they click a button. The user will input his/her full name in the alert view and press confirm. I store this value to the database.

I want to show another alert controller when the save operation is complete in the database. I tried to do that in the completion section of the call, but it didn't work. Here is the code I tried:

```
 @IBAction func changeNamePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Full Name", message: "Please enter your name as you want it displayed in your profile", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default) { (_) in
            if let field = alertController.textFields![0] as? UITextField {
                // store your data
                self.userObject.name = field.text
                self.nameLabel.text = field.text
                SwiftSpinner.show("Updating Full Name")
                let errorFound: NSError? = self.utilities.changeFullName(field.text!)
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
                if(errorFound?.domain != "")
                {
                    print("Error Updating Name Change: \(errorFound?.description)")
                }else{
                    print("No Errors Found")
                }
            } else {
                // user did not fill field
            }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }
        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Your Full Name"
        }
        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: displayNameChangeConfirmation)

    }

    func displayNameChangeConfirmation()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Updated", message: "Your full name has been successfully updated.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

when the above code was executed, I got this error:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Any idea what is going on and how it can be fixed? Should I be following a different approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change call of method "displayNameChangeConfirmation"
from completion task to Confirm action, In case of success

Current case , you try to show 2nd controller right after showing 1st one which is already showing

Comment: Can you please elaborate more...got confused by the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: displayNameChangeConfirmation) //
```

To

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) // this completion handler is called immediately once alert is appeared so put it nil.
```

Call displayNameChangeConfirmation after line print("No Errors Found") as below:

```
        print("No Errors Found" + field.text!)
        dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.displayNameChangeConfirmation()
        })
```